# Odd Padding Behavior on Dropdown Submenu

Tags: drop-down-menu, submenu, cascadingdropdown

I have two issues going on...

1. my submenu disappears when I am not on hover (item 3). I probably should have the submenu appear under the menu, but moving things had been tedious.
2. my second submenu (item 3 again) has this weird padding like issue. I'm not sure what's causing that.

This is my first CSS dropdown. Any tips on cleaning up the code would be VERY appreciated! I've been working on this for two days now.

[https://prof-lizmi.com/ca273/wk6/advanced-navbar/start-dropdown.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

I've tried a number of positioning states and top, left movements.